# What kind of lighting to buy when there is no previous installed to use as a reference?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

When moving to a new house and there are no lightbulbs/lights etc how do we know what kind of lighting we should buy?
Is this something standard?
And how do we decide on what is the best type in terms of power consumption (i.e. cheaper)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install any off the (local) shelf armature, connect the wires and mount it to the wall/ceiling.

If you want power efficiency then you should prefer LED lighting which are currently some of the more efficient lighting solutions.

One of the factors to take into account is how much light it needs to emit and where it needs to go. A single 100W incandescent bulb in a large hall is not going to cut it.

If you are wondering which bulbs to put into existing armatures then it's very likely a standard connector. For mains that is an [edison base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edison_screw) or [bayonet mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayonet_mount) in the UK.

Comment: Sorry for the basic questions. What do you mean by "shelf armature"? The lights that are in the ceiling? Don't we need an electrician for the installation? Also what about the lamps that we need to put e.g. in the bathroom. I think for there usually there is a "socket" and we just need to know what bulb to buy, no?

Comment: off-the-shelf (was a typo) aka something you can find lying on the shelf in your local home depot/interior decoration store.

Comment: @jim You can read armature in ratchet freaks answer as "any light fixture or light bulb  that will fit your existing light fixtures". If you have any dimmer switches installed in your house and you buy dim-able led bulbs you may need replace the dimmer switch if it is not a modern one rated for led lights.

Comment: @Alaskaman:That is my question. How do I know that it fits without buying it and trying it?

Comment: @Jim the 2 most common edisons will be E27 which is 27 mm (about 1") in diameter and E17 which is 17 mm (about 1/2") in diameter. easy enough to distinguish at a glance.